# `funopen`, `setvbuf`, and guarantees?

Tags: bsd

BSD manpages for `funopen` include the following text:

> Read and write I/O functions are allowed to change the underlying buffer on fully buffered or line buffered streams by calling setvbuf(3). They are also not required to completely fill or empty the buffer. They are not, however, allowed to change streams from unbuffered to buffered or to change the state of the line buffering flag. They must also be prepared to have read or write calls occur on buffers other than the one most recently specified.

I find that last sentence profoundly insufficient to make any actual decisions, so much so that I'd be uncomfortable with *any* use of `setvbuf` that doesn't just leave all buffers sitting around for the entire lifetime of the virtual file.

Because there's no constraints stated about how long old buffers can hang around or have calls made on them!

I *presume* it's just for however long it takes for the old buffer's data to be consumed, but if you go by just that text as written, this implies *all* buffers *ever* given to `setvbuf` for this file can be reused internally at any time, whenever and however *the implementation feels like doing*.

What's the real-world expectation? What are the implied guarantees that actual practicing BSD developers know to trust when exercising this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Well since there's no built-in in way in STDIO or in the `funopen()` API of telling if/when a buffer's data has been entirely consumed (unless perhaps you're using NetBSD's more recent `funopen2()` and have supplied a `flushfn` that communicates with `readfn` and/or `writefn` through some private global object related to their `cookie` parameter), there is indeed no way for the "Read and write I/O functions" *in and of themselves* to determine when any buffers they previously supplied have become wholly unreferenced and empty.

In theory a calling program could share the `cookie` with the main program's logic and use it to reference a flag that could be set after a successful `fflush()` and cleared before any new `fread()` or `fwrite()` on the related `FILE` object (just as could be done with `funopen2()`'s `flushfn`.  That way the calling program could share with the `readfn` and/or `writefn` that all data in all buffers had been consumed.

In practice though, in native BSD implementations at least, `setvbuf()` tries flushing the current and one and only buffer anyway (albeit without checking for errors, though the default flush function does set the internal error flag if a write fails), and will even free the current buffer if it was automatically/internally allocated before assigning the newly supplied buffer (or allocating a new one if requested).

Note also that using `setvbuf()` with a `NULL` `buf` parameter and expecting it to be automatically allocated may, in the case of a memory allocation failure, break the rule about not changing the buffering state.

I'm not sure what the rationale was for allowing `readfn` and/or `writefn` to call `setvbuf()` in the first place.  It all seems rather fragile and pointless on first glance, to me at least.  (The related comment in the code is *"to allow exchange buffering"*.)  The default functions do not make use of this allowance.

So, what would your reason be for wanting to call `setvbuf()` from either the `readfn` or `writefn`, and especially why would you consider having either function make a call to `setvbuf()` more than once (and especially with a different (or `NULL`) buffer each time)?